# FogBugz - Include all cases assigned to myself and Project <> "Project A" and Project <> "Project B"

Tags: fogbugz, fogbugz-on-demand

Is there a way in FogBugz to create a filter which is:

> [All] [open] [cases] assigned to [Developer A] with the exception of 1 or more projects.

I've had a trawl through Google and the FogBugz forums but couldn't find anything.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work:

```
status:"Open" assignedto:"Developer A": -project:"Project A" -project:"Project B"
```

and you might want to tuck on this as well:

```
view:"Outline"
```

if you're on FogBugz 7.

To find the help for the search system, let the search-box up to the right in the webpage be empty, and click the search button, this will give you some rudimentary help, and you can click on to the help page about the "search axis" to find all the fields you can query on.

AND is implicit, OR must be specified, hence there's an AND between all the search-terms in my query, which should give you what you want.

Comment: Additionally, those project names can get long, so you can use the ixProject of the project instead of its name.  Edit the project and get the ixProject=123 from the URL of the edit page.  Then search on this:

status:open assignedto:joe -project:"=123" -project:"=234"